# Auto Refresh Select Menu's in Web Apps

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is it possible to refresh the Select Menu's without hitting the controller and regenerating the whole Select Menu in the Controller and sending back to the respective Div ?
I can sent the data in JSON format from the Controller but I don't want to sent the entire Div all over ... .. because it breaks the DRY principle . This is a very common scenario , I am wondering if its possible to make the Select Menu listen to some object in the JS , so that , if that Object is modified , refresh the Select Menu accordingly .... The object can be made like {value,text} etc ...Does any one have any pointers ?

How the select gets generated in the Web App ?

```
<form>
<content>
<div id=unique id>
<for each in some model>
   <option> <value>
</div>
<content>
```

We have many such forms with Select Menu's ... Everytime we tend to write select to another file and call it again .

```
<div id=unique id>
<for each in some model>
   <option> <value>
</div>
```

Why not re-use ?
1) Because we only need to refresh the Select not the Content 
2) The data obtained in the main page is from some dictionary (pre-populated from DB) , in the refresh , we might obtain the data from the DB direct ...

So sticking to dry principle can I just populate SELECT contents by some UI listeners to some Object ? If the Object changes , refresh the select with new value . I will just write AJAX to get the JSON of the new SELECT MENU .

Comment: The answer is probably yes, but we need more details if you want a more... exact response. From your question I only understand that somewhere you have a select, that you populate from the response of an ajax request sent to a controller (probably some MVC system), part that is not exactly relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
$.each(jsonData, function(index){
    $('select').append('<option value="'+jsonData[index].value+'">'+jsonData[index].text+'</option>');
});
```

When JSON Data looks like:

```
[
  {
    "value":1,
    "text":"Text for First Item"
  },
  {
    "value":2,
    "text":"Text for 2nd Item"
  }
]
```

Hope I understand your question ;-)

Comment: Yes this is something like this I need . Was wondering if I can bind the select to this jsonData and is the jsonData changes , do this ... sort of thing ?

Comment: Think then you need to compare the new received json data with the last received and compare them...

Comment: I think Angular.js has an inbuilt way to do this . They have some MVC frame work on client side . Comparing is the trick thing . When to compare ? Ideally it should be the Select is populated from a variable say X . If X Changes Select Changes , but this is like an event it should register to ... Thats a bit complex . Also I want to destroy the Event when we navigate out of the page ... to avoid Memory Leaks .

Comment: That's might be possible (I know it's working in backbone js but then a complete recreation of the element is neccesary. I don't know any argument against this way because it's just a clientside operation

Comment: Backbone js sounds intersting .